# Update whole row

Tags: mysql

Does MySQL have an UPDATE syntax that would allow me to update a whole row (not individual columns)?, something like this:

```
UPDATE      `table1`
LEFT JOIN   `table2` USING (`myColumn`)
SET         `table1`.* = `table2`.*
```

- Both `table1` and `table2` have the exact same structure.
- The column names are variable, and subject to change.

Unfortunately I can't use a [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) query because the tables were badly designed and I'm not at liberty to modify them. The joining column doesn't have a unique index assigned to it, it only has a normal index.

Comment: "*Both `table1` and `table2` have the exact same structure*" violates the principle of orthogonal design; furthermore, "*[t]he column names are ... subject to change*" is indicative of poor schema design.  Can you elaborate on how this comes to be a requirement?

Comment: @eggyal, I agree that the schema is very poorly designed (in many ways). Unfortunately the table has 100 columns, I don't want to manually write the list out for the query (because of future changes).

Comment: @eggyal, The same structure is not due to the poor design, one is a temporary table: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table2` LIKE `table1`. I'm doing a lot of merging data from CSV files.

Comment: In that case, what data does `table2` contain?  Perhaps the `UPDATE` can be performed without the temporary table.

Comment: @eggyal, I'm using `LOAD DATA` to import CSVs into a temporary table, I then have to find which records already exist, and do filtering before updating the live tables with new data.

Comment: Maybe I will just have to delete the old records and then an insert.

Answer (score 1):

*"The column names are variable, and subject to change"* - This is so wrong, if you rely on column order not col names, one day it will hit you in the head. Update will work with explicit col names: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93621/1).

Comment: `table2` is an exact copy of `table1`'s structure, I created with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 LIKE table1`

Comment: You can create one more temporary table ids, store ids of rows you need to update there, drop that rows from table1 and `insert into table1 select table2.* from table2 right join ids on ids.id=table2.id`. This solution is ugly, but under this condition any solution will be ugly, I think.